# Independent qt application and dependency packing in windows and linux

Tags: linux, qt, deployment

I made an application for Linux using QtCreator. The application uses two external libraries, [qextserialport](http://code.google.com/p/qextserialport/) and [qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/). I want to deploy the app such that all libraries it depends on are deployed alongside the executable file.

When I made an application for Windows I just copied the .dll files into the app.exe folder, and it works. But how do I do this on Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linux you can:

1) static-link the dependencies

or

2) pack dependencies windows-style and set environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH pointing to the subdirectory containing the dynamic libraries

[updated]

read `man ld`, may be you will have to compile static versions of the libraries if they are not compiled by default ([look at this tutorial if you can't tell the difference](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html)).

Great comment by synthesizerpatel, if the library uses autoconf (a lot of linux software do), it has options like --enable-shared and --enable-static.

Comment: i have read about static linking but not getting what to do.Can you give detail .

Comment: Compile the library as static (most have an option for this, --enable-shared or --enable-static if it's built by autoconf / configure). When you have a static lib, it'll be libname.a, as opposed to libname.so, or libname.dylib (mac). Then when you're linking, just specify the path to the shared lib as part of the objects, or -L/where/the/dota/lives -lname

Comment: @Sanjay This answer contains both methods of doing what you want that I would suggest, and therefore I advise you mark it as such!

Comment: Neither of this will be necessary if he goes the canonical route of distributing packages suitable for the major distributions, right?

Comment: i Tried the window style,and set LD_LIBRARY_PATH .Bt the problem is ldd command shows libqwt.so.6 as dependancy but there are 4 files in lib with the name libqwt.so with different version.Do i need all libqwt.so files or particular file shown by ldd.

Comment: @pmr: true in theory, in the real world many people opt for the windows-style packaged applications as it is far easier to support.

Comment: @sanjay: you need only the file pointed by ldd (I think some of the duplicate files you see are symbolic links to this one)