# All dependancies I need

Tags: linux, qt

I am programming a short application in Qt in linux. I want to run it on another computer with the executable file.
I took the executable file and I run it on my other computer and I get this error:

```
    ./BGE_GUI: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.7' not found (required by ./BGE_GUI)
./BGE_GUI: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by ./BGE_GUI)
./BGE_GUI: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Gui.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by ./BGE_GUI)
./BGE_GUI: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5: version `Qt_5' not found (required by ./BGE_GUI)
```

So I want to add the dependencies with the executable file. How could I get all the dependencies that are needed by my application file?
I work on ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I think you are looking for a way to deploy your application. Take a look here, it might help you http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html

Comment: Also this topic might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983507/independent-qt-application-and-dependency-packing-in-windows-and-linux?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deploy Qt Application binaries on Ubuntu with shared libs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28973921/deploy-qt-application-binaries-on-ubuntu-with-shared-libs)

Comment: This question has been asked a hundred times....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were on windows i would have adviced to use Dependency walker

found this subject that could help you have a equivalent tools on Linux :

[Dependency Walker equivalent for Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977298/dependency-walker-equivalent-for-linux)

this kind of tool will list you all the dependencies that you need.

Comment: On linux, run the ldd command `ldd executable_name` to list all the shared libs to be deployed.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. But how could I collect all these dependecies automaticaly in folder?